# How to hide source code of my flutter plugin so that nobody can see the same while using?

Tags: flutter, plugins, flutter-dependencies

We have developed a flutter plugin and we don't want to share the source code with the customer. If they are adding our plugin to their app there are possibilities to get the code from pub cache . So we want to deliver our product without revealing the source code.I just wanted to know if there is a way to implement this.It would be a great help if somebody could help me to do this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna use a local package/plugin you needn't share it or publish it on pub.dev. You can create a new folder which would take plugins files, within your project.

```
├── android
├── ios
├── lib
├── packages
│   └── custom_button
└── test
```

you can use it directly but if you have created this file like a flutter package style you should implement it in your project's `pubspec.yaml`.

**Like this:**

```yaml
dependencies:
 custom_button:
    path: packages/custom_button
```